# How to make icon and text change color at the same time on hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have `divs` that each contain an `<i>` and a `<p>`.  On hover, I want both to change color at the same time.  Checking some of the answers here on the forum, I managed to, but on hover, the other `divs` turn all to white. (I'm using Bootstrap 4).

```css
.category-box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 11px rgba(170, 192, 205, 0.49);
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.category-box p {
  color: #1F2833;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.category-box:hover {
  background-color: #0074e1;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.category-box-container i {
  color: #0074e1;
}

.category-box-container:hover p,
.category-box-container:hover i {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-box i {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Fontawsome CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mx-auto category-box-container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Sobre Paygol -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
        <p>Sobre Paygol</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Vendedores -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
        <p>Vendedores</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Compradores -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <p>Compradores</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Países -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>
        <p>Países</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Desarrolladores -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
        <p>Desarrolladores</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Términos -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
        <p>Términos</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!-- /Términos -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using a `:hover` selector for the whole container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `:hover` that affects the entire container/parent. Code changes in comments.

```css
.category-box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 11px rgba(170, 192, 205, 0.49);
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.category-box p {
  color: #1F2833;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.category-box:hover {
  background-color: #0074e1;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.category-box-container i {
  color: #0074e1;
}

.category-box:hover p, 
.category-box:hover i { /* Renamed from `.category-box-container` */
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-box i {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Fontawsome CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mx-auto category-box-container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Sobre Paygol -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
        <p>Sobre Paygol</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Vendedores -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
        <p>Vendedores</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Compradores -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <p>Compradores</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Países -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>
        <p>Países</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Desarrolladores -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
        <p>Desarrolladores</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Términos -->
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="col category-box">
        <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
        <p>Términos</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!-- /Términos -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked just fine! The `<p>` hover state keeps showing the underline line, even though it has a `text-decoration: none` Any thoughts?

Comment: Fixed it! I added a `*:hover { text-decoration: none !important;}`

Comment: That is not a good practice to include a global selector unless you really want to use no text-decoration globally. Although since you have included the category box inside `a` the anchor by default acts as a link and thus on hover it shows the underline. You may want to use `.category-box-container a:hover { text-decoration: none;
}`